# Is it necessary to create two tables in SQLite and two modal classes to store and retrieve two ViewHolder classes in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Here I am talking about multiview types RecyclerView in android studio.
Or let us say, what is the best approach?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Later @Kozmotronik figured out for me.